# Calculate difference between start angle and current measured angle/ Circle Calculation

Tags: android, math, accelerometer, geometry, android-sensors

In my application i want to calculate the angle difference between the start of the application and current measured angle. Therefore i use `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`  and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` to get current orientation. This works quite well. Here my code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
        return;
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        valuesAccelerometer = lowPass(event.values.clone(),
                valuesAccelerometer);
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        valuesMagneticField = lowPass(event.values.clone(),
                valuesMagneticField);
    }
    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrixR, matrixI,
            valuesAccelerometer, valuesMagneticField);
    if (success) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);
        azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
        if (azimuth < 0.0f) {
            azimuth += 360.0f;
        }
        if (!initAz) {
            startAzimuth = azimuth;
            initAz = true;
        } else {
            float difAz = startAzimuth-azimuth;
            Log.i("Test", "" +"Dif: "+ difAz +  "Act_Value " + azimuth + " Start_Value " + startAzimuth);
        }
    }

}
```

To describe my Problem here an example from Logcat:

```
 Dif: -220.63545    Act_Value 358.24    Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: -220.7943     Act_Value 358.40    Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: -221.49236    Act_Value 359.10    Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: 137.07309     Act_Value 0.53      Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: 135.63617     Act_Value 1.97      Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: 135.16443     Act_Value 2.44      Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: 136.15468     Act_Value 1.457     Start_Value 137.61
 Dif: 136.72552     Act_Value 0.88      Start_Value 137.61
```

If my current Measurement turns from 360° to 0° my difference angel turns wrong. How could i handle this quite clean, so it works for left and right rotation.

Comment: Can't you just do `if(difAz < 0) difAz+=360;`?

Comment: Generally speaking, difference measurements are `diff = final-initial`, so it would be `float difAz = azimuth - startAzimuth` in addition to what Heuster said.